# 5.5" portable CRT television with several black lines

Tags: tv, crt, portable

I have this monochromatic chinese television largely manufactured in the past decade, 
marketed under several brands (Coby, Curtis, Precision, etc). This one in particular have a external AC DC converter of 1.6A and 12v and AV out. His cover is  [like this one but silver](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/239928/how-dangerous-are-portable-crt-televisions).

In this photo as you can see, it shows **several horizontal black lines** along the image **vertically expanded**. I already opened it to clean (had small cockroaches living in with his feces). This photo was taken while plugged in with a alternative smaller and lighter ac dc adapter (1.5 a 12v). The original power adapter seems to be faulty, because in addition of this lines the screen becomes unstable, as if closing.

I wonder if someone could give me a answer or clue about this problem. Thanks.

[image: Chinese CRT 5.5" horizontal black lines]

[image]

Comment: It almost looks like the vertical deflection amplitude is *much* too large - it appears that we can see the individual, interlaced horizontal scan lines with the lines getting closer together towards the bottom - a sign of non-linearity.  As usual, check for failed electrolytic capacitors around the vertical output stage / IC.

Answer (score 4):

The main board had some opaque solder. I just heated those to the melting point and now the TV displays the image with correct deflection amplitude.

[image]
[image]

Comment: now you can use that flyback red wire to fry the Brazilian cockroaches ;) if you decide to retire the set.

Comment: the expanded vertical indicated excessive vertical sweep voltage slew rate

Comment: The cockroaches where four (very stealth ones), 3 crushed in flight and one fugitive. 

Brazilian... You saw the Globo logo for sure.